# CiviCRM in a separate database keeps testing the Drupal database on update

Tags: database, drupal-9

I've installed Drupal (9) and CiviCRM (5.59) in separate databases using `drush site:install` and `cv core:install` in that order. The drupal database connection is set in `settings.php`, and the civi database connection is set in `civicrm.settings.php`.

It works, until it doesn't.

Amongst others (I think), on a Drupal core update, Civi believes it lives in the Drupal database and tries to run tests there. It doesn't have the right permissions (TRIGGERS and such), and everything fails. It also creates all civi tables in the drupal db (I think already on `drush site:install`, which it never uses during operation.

What is wrong ? How can I tell CiviCRM to always work in it's own database ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have civicrm_entity installed? See https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity/issues/3299224#comment-15013847

Comment: I have, and that would explain why these tables are created in the wrong database. I'm not sure if it explains why a drupal core update would try to use those tables ..